# Making text = an int (cocos2d iPhone)

Tags: text, nsstring, cocos2d-iphone, int, splash-screen

I have an int named percentComplete (for a SplashScene). I need to make that into text (CCLabelBMFont) that will have the same number as the int, and be updated when the int is. Think of a loading screen that has a number represent how far it is until the game can start (77%). I've started with this so far. I end up with a warning. percentComplete is the int, percentCompleteText is a CCLabelBMFont

```
    -(void)displayPercentCompleteText:(id)sender {
    percentCompleteText = (CCLabelBMFont *) [self getChildByTag:kTagPercentComplete];
    [percentCompleteText setString:[percentComplete getPercentCompleteAsString]]; //Invalid receiver type 'int'
    percentCompleteText.position = ccp(111, 111); //CHANGE POSITION
    //SCHEDULE UPDATE EVERY .01s
}   

    -(NSString *)getPercentCompleteAsString {
        return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", percentComplete];
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming `-(NSString *)getPercentCompleteAsString` is in the same class as `-(void)displayPercentCompleteText:(id)sender` and `percentComplete` is a member variable (ivar) of that class ..

Change the line:

```
[percentCompleteText setString:[percentComplete getPercentCompleteAsString]]
```

to:

```
[percentCompleteText setString:[self getPercentCompleteAsString]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", percentComplete];
```

what if you change the line to

```
return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", percentComplete];
```

instead of double..